# Azure Devops stakeholder access permission issue

Tags: azure-devops, user-controls

I have added a external user to organization as a stakeholder. The organization has 3 projects but the stakeholder is given access to only 1 project as project contributor.
When I login as stakeholder he has access to all the 3 projects.
Kindly help to rectify this issue

I was expecting stakeholder to have access to only the assigned project

Answer (score 0):

Step1:

Sign into your organization and go to Organization settings--Users.

Then, select ... and select the option Manage user.

You can manage the user access by only selecting the project you want him to access.

[image]

Step2:

You can check if the user has been added to some groups in Organization settings-- Security--Permissions, for example Project Collection Administrators. The user in PCA groups can access every project in the organization.